# WPF populate information on a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**EDITED** I have removed the Name and Result collections to simply bind the AllResults properties. However, I can't see any real value in there, only entries that match with the number of values I should see but the content is not there.

I have the following XAML.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">SomeTextHere</TextBlock>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllResults}></ListView>          
    </Grid>
```

And the following ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region Properties

            private ObservableCollection<Results> _AllResults;

            public ObservableCollection<Results> AllResults
            {
                get
                {
                    return _AllResults;
                }
                set
                {
                    _AllResults = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region PropertyChanged

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }
            }

            #endregion           
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel is being called by an instance that sets the AllResults variable like this:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = PaneResultsControl.MyViewModelInstance; // Return the instance of the ViewModel.
myViewModel.AllResults = results;
```

What is failing on my logic that prevents me to populate the list of Results and Names? If I pass other values like a single string and try to binding to a TextBlock, it works like a charm but I am having trouble trying to fill in a GridView.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` so it knows where to get the data from:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllResults}">
...
```

However, you have done the additional very odd step of trying to break out your primary collection into two separate collections (`Name` and `Result`) and it appears you are then trying to bind your templates to *those*. That just won't work. Once inside a data template, the data context switches to the bound object, so even if you had access to `Name` and `Result` (which is possible to get) they are still just collections, not the individual piece of data you want.

An `ItemsControl` can only have one source, of one type of object. Instead of breaking your collections out, consider binding directly to the properties on the `Results` class and using converters or calculated properties if you need to transform the data for display

Comment: I edited my code but still doesn't work. It displays the right amount of entries but the content is not there.

Comment: I was able to fix it now! After I did the binding for the two columns, I started having an "Item collection must be empty before using ItemsSource" exception and I fixed it using a <ListView.View> tag to wrap the <GridView>

Answer (score 1):

Change notification is built in to the ObservableCollection so you can do away with creating new collections and property change notification.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Name { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> Result { get; set; }

private List<Results> _AllResults;

public List<Results> AllResults
{
    get
    {
        return _AllResults;
    }
    set
    {
        _AllResults = value;

        Name.Clear();
        Result.Clear();

        foreach (Results results in _AllResults)
        {
            Name.Add(results.Name);
            Result.Add(results.Succeed ? "Pass" : "Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your list view has no DataSource, you would probably want to set the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection on your viewmodel. This collection should probably be made up of another class.

```
public ObservableCollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

public class Result 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Result{ get; set; }
}


<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource={Binding Path=Results}>...
```

Comment: I tried this approach (I updated my code) but still doesn't work when I bind to AllResults property.

Comment: I was able to fix it now! After I did the binding for the two columns, I started having an "Item collection must be empty before using ItemsSource" exception and I fixed it using a <ListView.View> tag to wrap the <GridView>